# spyon() or jasmine.createobject to return observable array

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write unit-test test cases for an angular application. I have a service that return Observable which I am currently trying to test.

I have tried using Observable.of() which didn't seem to work.
Following are the files..

the service method returning observable using httpclient. i have tried to spyon 
with return value observable of array.

terminal-carding.service.ts

```
 getTerminalCompanies() {
return this.http.get(this.maintenanceSharedService.getTerminalCompaniesUrl())
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleGetTerminalCompaniesError)
```

}

terminal-carding.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular/main';
import { TableWidgetComponent } from '../../../widgets/table-widget/table-widget.component';
import { TerminalCardingComponent } from './terminal-carding.component';
import { TerminalCardingService } from './terminal-carding.service';
import { AppService } from './../../../app.service';
import { UtilService } from '../../../shared/util.service';
import { DashboardSharedService } from './../../../shared/dashboard-shared.service';
import { TableWidgetService } from '../../../widgets/table-widget/table-widget.service';
import { SecuritySharedService } from '../../../shared/security-shared.service';
import { MaintenanceSharedService } from '../../../shared/maintenance-shared.service';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/observable';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BaseHttpClientService } from '../../../shared/common/base-http-client.service';

fdescribe('TerminalCardingComponent', () => {
  let component: TerminalCardingComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TerminalCardingComponent>;
  let maintenanceSharedService: MaintenanceSharedService;
  let service: TerminalCardingService;
  let getMaintenanceModuleAuthPermissionsSpy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        TerminalCardingComponent,
        TableWidgetComponent,
      ],
      providers: [
        AppService,
        UtilService,
        DashboardSharedService,
        TableWidgetService,
        SecuritySharedService,
        MaintenanceSharedService,
        TerminalCardingService,
        BaseHttpClientService
      ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = TestBed.get( TerminalCardingService );
    maintenanceSharedService = TestBed.get( MaintenanceSharedService );
    getMaintenanceModuleAuthPermissionsSpy = spyOn(maintenanceSharedService, 'getMaintenanceModuleAuthPermissions').and.returnValue({});
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TerminalCardingComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should resolve test data', async(() => {
    const terminalCompanies = [{
      terminalCompany: 'aaa'
    },
    {
      terminalCompany: 'bbb'
    },
    {
      terminalCompany: 'ccc'
    }];
    const spy = spyOn(service, 'getTerminalCompanies').and.returnValue(Observable.of(terminalCompanies));
      component.ngOnInit();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      console.log(component.terminalCompanies[0].terminalCompany);
      expect(component.terminalCompanies[0].terminalCompany).toEqual(terminalCompanies[0].terminalCompany);
    }));

  });
```

---

```
   Error: i am getting following error....
Failed: observable_1.Observable.of is not a function
```

Comment: Observable.of() should work too, Which the RxJS version are you using?

Comment: What is the error are you getting?

Comment: We are using rxjs version 5.4.1 ...i have tried below method also....

Comment: We are using rxjs version 5.4.1 ...i have tried below method also....    it('should resolve test data', async(() => {
    const terminalCompanies = [{
      terminalCompany: 'aaa'
    }];
    const spy = spyOn(service, 'getTerminalCompanies').and.returnValue(Observable.of(terminalCompanies));   .... I am getting below error... Expected [ Object({ terminalCompany: 'aaa' }) ] to equal <jasmine.objectContaining(Object({ terminalCompany: 'aaa' }))>.
Error: Expected [ Object({ terminalCompany: 'aaa' }) ] to equal <jasmine.objectContaining(Object({ terminalCompany: 'aaa' }))>.

Comment: you are spying two times, and ` const cardingService = jasmine.createSpyObj('TerminalCardingService', ['getTerminalCompanies'])
      .and.returnValues({});` will not work.

Comment: I have not created twice....i just explained you what are all the different ways tried. In two ways like  ,  one is using "spyon" and one more using "jasmine.createSpyObj".

Comment: here the issue in the line  `expect(component.terminalCompanies).toEqual(terminalCompanies);`, Issuue is, you are doing `object === object` which returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue in the line

`expect(component.terminalCompanies).toEqual(terminalCompanies);`

Issue is, you are doing `array === array` which returns `false`.

So, to test, you should compare the values in the array. i.e.

`expect(component.terminalCompanies[0].terminalCompany).toEqual(terminalCompanies[0].terminalCompany);`

Hope it helps...

Comment: i have updated the code as per your suggestion but still i am getting error like "Failed: observable_1.Observable.of is not a function" and also updated the latest code

Comment: @priya ,  since `Failed: observable_1.Observable.of is not a function` is the error, you need to import `of` from RXJS. Add import like this -> `import "rxjs/add/observable/of";   // For RxJs  5.x`

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion but still  am getting same error...i.e   import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';....and also tried with as mentioned below...  const spy = spyOn(service, 'getTerminalCompanies').and.returnValue(Observable.from(terminalCompanies));...but still i will get same error Failed: observable_1.Observable.from is not a function

Comment: @priya, problem is: `of` is not imported properly. The RxJS has different syntax to import operators in different RxJS versions. So try this -> `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';`

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion ,still i am getting same error like Failed: observable_1.Observable.of is not a function

Comment: @priya, Can you bring code to the state where you said "We are using rxjs version 5.4.1. i have tried below method also.... it('should resolve test data', async(() => { const terminalCompanies = [{ terminalCompany: 'aaa' }]; const spy = spyOn(service, 'getTerminalCompanies').and.returnValue(Observable.of(terminalCompanies)); I am getting below error. Expected [ Object({ terminalCompany: 'aaa' }) ] to equal <jasmine.objectContaining(Object({ terminalCompany: 'aaa' }))>. Error: Expected [ Object({ terminalCompany: 'aaa'}) ] to equal <jasmine.objectContaining(Object({ terminalCompany: 'aaa' }))>"